# issue with multibinding dependency property

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I am working on custom control.

I have three dependency property as mentioned below. 
Now depending on the control height, width and a range provided by the user, I have to calculate a value and
display it in the custom control.

I am trying to use a multibinding where I can bind all these three values and my multivalue converter will do some calculation on this
and returns me the appropriate value.

The problem is I do not know to bind this value in the styles as multivalue converter binding.

Dependency Properties:

```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ControlHeight", typeof(double), typeof
   (TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(150D));

    public double ControlHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ControlHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControlHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ControlWidth", typeof (double), typeof 
   (TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public double ControlWidth
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(ControlWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ControlWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RangeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Range", typeof (double), typeof 
   (TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public double Range
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(RangeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RangeProperty, value); }
    }
```

Style (I have not written the binding): If the properties are available in the same style than I can do it
using ElementName binding. But in this case atlease may be for height and width it is possible. But Range is a direct dependency property
which I have to bind in my style (I mean there is no way I can do an ElementName binding)

```
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource   
   CalculateConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path=""></Binding>
                                    <Binding Path=""></Binding>
                                    <Binding Path=""></Binding>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `RelativeSource`.

```
<Binding Path="Range" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}"></Binding>
```